# Request-URI Too Large (414 error) in jarida theme

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, themes

when i submit my Get request too large it showing me following error :

Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL\'s length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
Apache Server at c61.servage.net Port 80

Please Give me solution for this.

May be my page is not loading properly.

Comment: You cannot use that much data in a single GET. I suggest you break your form down into multiple forms.

Comment: thanks , but is it possible to increase loading time using htaccess ?

Comment: No, not in htacess. You can in php.ini, but that depends on what your server hosts allow. If you do try increase the memory limit for get/post then you will be going down the wrong path, as it seldom works to fix the problem.

Comment: GET is restricted to 2048 length, so switch to POST instead

Comment: Thanks all . problem solved that is jquery confiscation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all . problem solved that is jquery confiscation